# Openssl does not read default values from openssl.cnf

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, configuration-files

I am using the following command to create a certificate request:

```
openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -out [filename].csr -passout pass:[password]
```

The `openssl.cnf` file is in the directory that I run the command from.
The problem is that I am still prompted to submit the values for country, state, locality, etc.
I want to do this programmatically, without someone having to step in and type these values. Shouldn't `openssl.cnf` provide the default values to be used? Am I missing an argument or something?

Comment: Use `openssl version -a | grep OPENSSLDIR` to see which configuration file OpenSSL is using. More correclty, its using `openssl.cnf`, but the question is where its coming from. In all setup's I am aware, OpenSSL apps never looks in `PWD`. You have to set `PWD` in an environmental variable `OPENSSL_CONF`, or you have to provide `PWD` as a `-config` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case the correct syntax would be:

```
openssl req -batch -config openssl.cnf -new -out [filename].csr -passout pass:[password]
```

A 2048b RSA private key will be generated at the same time in 'privkey.pem'.
If you prefer creating a request for a pre-existing key, add option :

```
-key [keyfile]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks... I managed to do it using an input file. The syntax is this:

openssl req -config openssl.cnf -new -out [filename].csr -passout pass:[password] < "install_ssl1.in"